# Why `(T)this` from Java can't work in scala?

Tags: java, scala, types

Given these Java class definitions:

```
class Base {
    int value;

    public <T extends Base> T self() {
        return (T) this;
    }

}

class Derived  extends Base {}
```

this Java code compiles fine:

```
new Derived().self();
```

but this Scala code fails to run:

```
(new Derived).self(); // runtime error
```

Rumtime error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: Derived cannot be cast to scala.runtime.Nothing$
```

Why it doesn't work, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In scala this method looks like `self[T <: Base](): T`. In `(new Derived).self()` you didn't specify the `T`. It means the most specific type - [`Nothing`](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/128).

So `(new Derived).self()` is actually `(new Derived).self[Nothing]()`.

You could try `(new Derived).self[Derived]()` or `val d: Derived = (new Derived).self()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you write wrong code. I tested in JDK 1.6.

```
new Derived().self();
(new Derived()).self();
```

are all OK.

But `(new Derived).self();` gives compile error!